# Media Player wont stop playing while using Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am having a little bit of an issue with the media player. Currently everything works perfectly except for this one part. I have a `recyclerview` that I am using to get the `URLs` and using that to play in the `mediaplayer`. The only issue is when I click on the position of the `recyclerview`, it will play the music, but when I click on another position is will overlap the current `mediaplayer` and won't stop it. I added the code for it to `stop` and `release` if the `mediaplayer` is playing but it wont work. If someone can give me some advice on how to fix this. My code is posted below.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private TextView btm_music_text;
private ImageView btm_play;
public static String title,body,url;
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btm_music_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_act_text);
    btm_play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_act_play);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainAct_RV);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //Database Ref
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/episodes");

    //Set up Firebase Database Adapter
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EpisodeReference, EpisodeViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EpisodeReference, EpisodeViewHolder>
            (EpisodeReference.class, R.layout.episode_layout, EpisodeViewHolder.class, mDatabase)

    //Populating View
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final EpisodeViewHolder viewHolder, final EpisodeReference model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setBody(model.getBody());
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    title = model.getTitle();
                    body = model.getBody();
                    url = model.getUrl();
                    Uri mUri = Uri.parse(url);

                    btm_music_text.setSelected(true);
                    btm_music_text.setText(title + ": " + body);

                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mUri);
                        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare(); //don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null){
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        btm_play.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.selector_play));
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        btm_play.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.selector_pause));
                    }
                    button_change();
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TITLE", model.getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("BODY", model.getBody());
                    intent.putExtra("URL", model.getUrl());
                    startActivity(intent);*/
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}

private void button_change(){
    btm_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer != null) {
                btm_play.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.selector_play));
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btm_play.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.selector_pause));
            }
        }
    });
}

public static class EpisodeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;



    public EpisodeViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        tv2.setText(body);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        tv1.setText(title);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a new MediaPlayer before stopping the previous one. Rearrange your code like this

```
@Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final EpisodeViewHolder viewHolder, final EpisodeReference model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setBody(model.getBody());
        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());

        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                title = model.getTitle();
                body = model.getBody();
                url = model.getUrl();
                Uri mUri = Uri.parse(url);

                btm_music_text.setSelected(true);
                btm_music_text.setText(title + ": " + body);

                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    btm_play.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.selector_play));
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    try {

                     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mUri);

             mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare(); //don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    btm_play.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.selector_pause));
                }

                button_change();
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("TITLE", model.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("BODY", model.getBody());
                intent.putExtra("URL", model.getUrl());
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: cool thanks, that worked but now I am running into the issue where it will stop the music player, but wont start the next song. If I hit the play button it will crash so I tried adding prepare and start but the app also crashes.

Comment: I got it to work, I just added a new mediaplayer in the if statement and it works fine now. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. Upvote my answer if it helped you in any way